# How can I bypass the 65K URL limit on .to_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

Here is my code. I'm really new to working with python and excel, so sorry in advanced. I'm trying to condense a rather large excel file, but I keep getting an error with a URL limit.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Excel Sheet') 
column_name = 'Category'
df[column_name] = df[column_name].str.strip().str.title()
unique_values = df[column_name].unique()


for unique_value in unique_values:
    df_output = df[df[column_name].str.contains(unique_value, na=False)]
    output_path = os.path.join('output', unique_value + ' .xlsx')
    df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value, index=False)
```

The error message is:

```
 Number of URLS is over Excel's limit of 65,530 URLS per worksheet.
```

Comment: Since this is an Excel software limit, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Search for _excel limits_  - note these are hard limits - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: You can't avoid this limit but, if it is an acceptable workaround, you could avoid converting the string to urls by passing the `strings_to_urls=False` parameter to xlsxwriter. See [Passing XlsxWriter constructor options to Pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas) and [Constructor options](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor),